# jasmine undefined not an object, can't find key

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

If I make the respond object from the httpbackend a single object instead of an array for 'data' it works fine.  But once I make it an array (even single element array) it doesn't want to work and gives me an error saying undefined is not an object (evaluating 'booking.Student.studentName'). Below is the code. Any ideas? Is it because lodash isn't doing its thing?

I have the following function in my controller

```
$scope.initBookings = function() {
  return $http.get('/api/bookings').then(function(response) {
    return $scope.bookings = _.map(response.data, function(booking) {
      booking.studentName = booking.Student.studentName;
      booking.slotDay = booking.Slot.day;
      booking.slotTime = booking.Slot.time;
      booking.subjectName = booking.Subject.name;
      return booking;
    });
  });
};
```

And my test is the following

```
it('should store bookings into $scope.bookings and create a $scope.bookingsTable', function() {
  expect(this.scope.bookings).toBeUndefined();
  this.scope.initBookings();
  this.httpBackend.expect('GET', '/api/bookings');
  this.httpBackend.flush();
  expect(this.scope.bookings).toBeDefined();
});

this.httpBackend.whenGET('/api/bookings').respond(function() {
  return [
    200, {
      data: [
        {
          Student: {
            studentName: 'John Die'
          },
          Slot: {
            day: 'today',
            time: 'now'
          },
          Subject: {
            name: 'maths'
          }
        }, {
          Student: {
            studentName: 'Jane Die'
          },
          Slot: {
            day: 'tomorrow',
            time: 'before'
          },
          Subject: {
            name: 'mathamatix'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
});
```

it is returning this

```
Object{data: [Object{Student: ..., Slot: ..., Subject: ...}, Object{Student: ..., Slot: ..., Subject: ...}]}
```

Comment: It seems strange that you are using the same variable (`booking`) to grab data from and assign to at the same time. Have you tried doing a console.log of that variable to see what it is returning?

Comment: how many return!!!

Comment: so? did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The controller function is a mess.

Note that you are making strange use of synchronous/asynchronous code to get data from server.

In order to make it more readable  and testable pls rewrite it fully async:

```
$scope.bookings = [];

$scope.initBookings = function() {
  $http.get('/api/bookings').then(function(response) {

    $scope.bookings = _.map(response.data, function(booking) {
      var out = {
        studentName: booking.Student.studentName,
        slotDay: booking.Slot.day,
        slotTime: booking.Slot.time,
        subjectName: booking.Subject.name
      };
      return out;
    });
  });
};

$scope.initBookings();
```

The body of lodash inner loop assigns other variables in add to the others, so the result object pushed in `$scope.bookings` become :

```
{
  studentName,
  Student:{
    studentName
  },
  slotDay,
  Slot: {
    day,
    time
  },
  slotTime,
  subjectName,
  Subject:{
    name
  }
}
```